# Blackberry on Eclipse - Simulator won't launch

Tags: eclipse, blackberry

When I try to debug a blackberry application in eclipse by selecting Debug As/Blackberry Simulator the simulator is never launched. The taskbar at the bottom says 'Launching DebugServer: (19%)'. It never gets past 19%. When I select **Run As**/Blackberry Simulator it works as expected. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general cause for a hang during debug startup is a problem with some port which is taken at the time of the debug session.

Can you try to close as many application/service as possible? (like, for instance, a VNC server which could use the same TCP port than a debug session)
Then check if you still have this issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That seemed to work. I rebooted my machine and only ran eclipse afterwards and was able to debug in the simulator. Any idea what port it is trying to use or if there's a way to change the port?

Comment: @cmour: nope, I do not know what exact port is involved or its configuration.

Comment: I spent a half a day figuring this out! I had to restart my computer to get it to work. It's like developing in the mid-90s developing for BlackBerry.