# Blackberry debugging with Intellij IDEA 8.0?

Tags: debugging, blackberry, intellij-idea

I have built a Blackberry project using bb-ant-tools working just fine. However, I cannot attach to the simulator. It says it is connected, but the simulator keeps saying "Debugger Attaching" and never finishes. Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: Is this the same (root cause) than http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1300489/blackberry-on-eclipse-simulator-wont-launch ?

Comment: I don't believe so. I will check it. Thanks for the info.

Comment: It is not that issue. I am able to connect with jdb and I have checked the ports. <br>jdb -connect com.sun.jdi.SocketAttach:hostname=10.10.254.37,port=8010 <br>Deferring uncaught java.lang.Throwable. <br>It will be set after the class is loaded. <br>Initializing jdb ... <br> > VM Started: resume <br>All threads resumed. <br> > Set deferred uncaught java.lang.Throwable <br>resume <br>All threads resumed

Comment: I've never got it to work.  I tend to write all code in IntelliJ and still use the JDE for compiling and debugging.

Comment: That is basically what I have done as well. I can find no other answer.